# how to write one java generic method to check value in generic list?

Tags: java, list, generics

Let say I have the `Student` class:

```
public class Student {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    //gettter and setter
}
```

I will have list of `Student`:

```
List<Student> list; //this includes all students
```

Now, when i retrieve `Student` details object, I will just have the `id` and need to check whether this `id` exists in list provided above or not. I can easily achieve this with simple java like this: creating one method which will take the list and student `id` as parameters and checking whether it is there in the list or not:

```
public static boolean valueExistInList(List<Student> list, String studentId) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(studentId)) {
        for (Student stu : list) {
            if (studentId.equals(stu.getId())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But my question is: can I also achieve same kind of functionality with `Java generics` method that will take list of any type of object and single value parameter(String or `Integer` or `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`) and checks whether single parameter exists in list or not and return boolean value?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

I am thinking if i can have method like this:

```
public static <T, U> boolean valueExistInList(List<T> list, U studentId) {
    boolean exists = false;
    //looping and checing whether studentId exists in list or not and 
    //then returning boolean value
    for(T t: list){
        //check studentId exists in list or not
        //if exists then return exists = true
        return exists;
    }
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: Can you change the data structure? It seems you need a hashmap more than a list

Comment: you will have to use the java reflection to identify the data type and search with this data type.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem with this generic method approach is that you do not know which method to call on each list element for checking. Additionally, you easily can imagine other boolean tests, not only `equals` (and not only on strings).

So you could go another step back: Let the caller of your method decide what boolean test should be made in the loop. You could express this as an interface:

```
interface BooleanExpression<T> { boolean test(T arg); }
```

Your generic method now changes to:

```
public static <T, U> boolean valueExistInList(List<T> list, BooleanExpression<T> tester) {
    for(T t: list) {
        if (tester.test(t)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You now can call this method as such:

```
List<Student> list = ...
final String studentId = ...
boolean result = valueExistsInList(list, new BooleanExpression<Student>() {
    @Override public boolean test(Student arg) {
         return arg.getId().equals(studentId);
    }
});
```

Having said this ... Java 8 provides such an interface. It is called a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). And it nicely fits into the new [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). So you now can write

```
List<Student> list = ...
String studentId = ...
boolean result = list.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getId().equals(studentId));
```

Comment: yes too bad i can not implement this as we are still using java 7.

Comment: i make it work based on your above recommendations. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can in combination with functions.

```
public static <T> boolean valueExistInList(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return list.stream().anyMatch(predicate);   
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
valueExistsInList(students, s -> s.getId().equals(studentId));
```

Or:

```
valueExistsInList(cars, c -> c.getBrand().equals("Tesla"));
```

In fact, you can do this even without a function, more directly like this:

```
boolean exists = students.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getId().equals(studentId));
```

**Java 7**

```
public interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean test(T t);
}
```

Then call your function like this:

```
valueExistInList(students, new Predicate<Student>() {
    boolean test(Student s) {
        return s.getId().equals(studentId);
    }
});
```

And the function `valueExistsInList` then becomes:

```
public static <T> boolean valueExistInList(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    for (T t : list) {
        if (predicate.test(t)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: I can not implement this solution as we are not upgraded to java 8.

Comment: Well you still can, but it would have to use anonymous classes, and you have to create your own `Predicate` interface (really easy).  I'll add a sample to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

List is an extension from the java Collection interface so you can do a lot of customizing by overriding the equals method so your contains method will function as you'd like. You would end up doing something *like* this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof String){
        String toCompare = (String) o;
        return id.equals(toCompare);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the (working) example below. By letting `Student` override from `ObjectWithId<U>` where `U` is the type of the id, you can have generic methods to check for the ids (in the Util class)

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     Student s = new Student();
     s.setId("studentId1");

     System.out.println(Util.hasCorrectId(s, "studentId1"));
  }
}

public class ObjectWithId<U>
{
   private U id;

  public U getId(){
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(U id){
    this.id = id; 
  }
}

public class Student extends ObjectWithId<String>
{

}

public class Util {

  public static <U> boolean valueExistInList(List<ObjectWithId<U>> list, U id) {

        for (ObjectWithId<U> obj : list) {
            if(hasCorrectId(obj, id)) return true;
        }

        return false;

  }

  public static <U> boolean hasCorrectId(ObjectWithId<U> obj, U id){
    return id.equals(obj.getId()); 
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this

```
public static <T, U> boolean valueExistInList(List<T> list, U input) {
for(T t: list)
{
    if (input.equals(t.getU)) // getU method should be there in T 
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

*But* you have to be careful while passing custom types. You have to override equals method.

Although this will work fine for types like `String`, `Integer` etc where `equals` is already overriden.

Comment: List<T> will have one of the property which will equal to passed T input.

Comment: @useDT In that case, to make it generic, your `T` type should have a contract (implement an interface).So that `T` will have a method that returns `U` which will be used to compare with `input`.